# Runtime ChartView Data Binding

Tags: delphi-10.2-tokyo, tcxgrid

as per question I am trying to dynamically create a cxGrid Chart View.

What i want to do is creating a single series and N groups. I cannot use the designer Data Binding since i am dynamically reading from a query and creating the Client Data Set Fields during RunTime.

I tried looking online but there are no explenations that i could find on my problem. I found some tips on how to create it with local data/variables, but not with Data Binding.

```
gridMainDBChartView1.CreateSeries;
gridMainDBChartView1.Series[0].DataBinding := {Supposed DataField}
```

Like, I tried Using more specific properties like grid.Series.DataBinding.FieldName or .ValueType, but it doesn't even show them in the preview.

Any Ideas on how i could do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just Dumb, there is actually a FieldName property accesible, but i don't know why it didn't show it to me on the autocomplete.